# ListView с WrapPanel - как сделать VerticalScrollBar?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Имеется `ListView` следующего вида:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" Grid.Row="1" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- шаблон в виде прямоугольника с картинкой и текстом -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <!-- покраска -->
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

`ListView` помещён в `Grid`, высота строки `"*"`.

Проблема заключается в том, что когда элементов становится достаточно много, `VerticalScrollBar` не появляются, и новые элементы продолжают вертикально растягивать `ListView`.

Пробовал отключать `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility`, помещать `ListView` в `ScrollViewer` - не помогает. Если добавить `MaxHeight="{Binding ListHeight}"` - работает, но при растягивании окна `ListView` остаётся того же размера, что и был (нужно, чтобы оно растягивалось).

Вопрос: как заставить появиться вертикальную прокрутку?

Comment: А по сколько элементов должно выводиться в одной строке 'WrapPanel'?

Comment: сделал все как у вас, у меня нормально. [скрин](http://i042.radikal.ru/1609/9f/58d67316b976.png)

Comment: @S.Kost сколько влезет по ширине `ListView` (у элементов разная толщина). Обычно по 3-4 штуки (не фиксировано).

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл (в определённой степени довольно корявое) решение:

В `ViewModel` к этому `UserControl` добавил следующее:

```
// в конструктор
Application.Current.Windows[0].SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(Window_SizeChanged);

// свойство, к которому привязан MaxHeight
public int ListHeight
{
    get
    {
        return (int)Application.Current.Windows[0].ActualHeight - _restHeight;
    }
}

// принуждение ListHeight к обновлению
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, System.Windows.SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    NotifyPropertyChanged("ListHeight");
}
```